# Loop with Pointers C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm having some troubles with this exercise that I'm working on. Basically with this `function void check(char *tel, char *c)` the first value of the array must be the number `2` and the others 8 must be a number between `0 and 9`.
If the conditions are met it will print `V`, otherwise it will print `F`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void check(char *tel, char *c){

int i;

if(*tel!=2) printf("Error\n"); 
                *c='F';
                return;  //I guess this return is wrong

if(*tel==2)
    for(i=0;tel[i]<9;i++){
        if(isdigit(tel[i]));

                   else{
               printf("Error!\n");
               *c='F';
               break;
                               return;}         //this one might be in bad use too

    }
 else

 *c='V';           //having troubles here.. i'm not seeing a way to fix this
 }

 int main(){

 char number[9]={2,3,4,5,6,7,4,5,3};
 char car;


 check(number,&car);

 printf("%c \n", car);

     system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This is C code, not C++.

Comment: you have an `else` with a `for`...If you want to use `if...else` you need to open and close it. This is only one problem, you have more there and this is C, not c++.

Comment: No, there is not an else with a for. How can people expect to read code that is anti-formatted?

Comment: Running with Visual Studio it wont give any error.. it runs compiling as a cpp file..

Comment: @JimBalter I've rolled the code back to the original version because I think the poor formatting is relevant to the question.

Comment: @JohnKugelman   Well, fine ... at least the proper formatting is in the history as a reference so people can see what this code really does.

Comment: ... but @hexacyanide didn't get the message.

Comment: I did not change the functionality of the code. No brackets, closures or functions were added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing curly braces around many of your `if` and `else` blocks. Properly indenting and formatting your code would go a long way.

```
if(*tel!=2) printf("Error\n"); *c='F'; return;
```

For instance, the above should be:

```
if (*tel != 2) {
    printf("Error\n");
    *c = 'F';
    return;
}
```

Please, please, please: **indent your code properly**.

---

**Edit:** To be more explicit, here's how your code looks after it's been reformatted. Do you see the errors now, the places where you're missing curly braces?

Hint: I've marked lines that should have them with a `/*******/` comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void check (char *tel, char *c) {
    int i;

    if (*tel != 2)                          /*******/
        printf("Error\n"); 

    *c = 'F';
    return;

    if (*tel == 2)                          /*******/
        for (i = 0; tel[i] < 9; i++) {
            if (isdigit(tel[i]))            /*******/
                ;
            else {
                printf("Error!\n");
                *c = 'F';
                break;
                return;
            }
        }
    else                                    /*******/
        *c = 'V';
}

int main() {
    char number[9] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 3};
    char car;

    check(number, &car);

    printf("%c \n", car);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: thats just an indentation problem.. the problem isnt up there but on the las lines of the funtion :(

Comment: The problem is there.. you didn't open the `IF` so.. you can't use the else statement after open the bracket on the `for`. Try it before tell us that is not the problem.

Comment: @RicardoCosta What does "just an indentation problem" mean? This is C, not Python. Try looking at the code ... it always sets *c = 'F' and returns. Here's a clue: you have a rep of 22, John has a rep of 64.7k ... which of you is more likely to be right?

Comment: Well yes, but it doesen't work neither.. the array that i have should be good and print 'V' not 'F' .

Comment: @RicardoCosta I didn't fix your code. I just reformatted it to highlight the errors in it.

Comment: yes, but ive already fix it(thanks) but it must be something missing :( let me edit the code

Comment: @RicardoCosta Please **do not** edit the code in such a way that it changes what it does ... that makes existing answers invalid. If you want to post new code, mark it as such and include it below the original code.

Comment: I dont know who approved Ricardo's suggested edit, but I've rolled back the changes, since it makes the answer look invalid.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of small problems with the code you have posted. This is the most immediately obvious to me:

```
if(*tel!=2) printf("Error\n"); *c='F'; return;  //I guess this return is wrong
```

Since you have decided not to use curly braces to segment off the if-branch logic, only the first statement - printf("Error\n"); is considered to be associated with your if check. That means that in every execution, the value of c will be set to 'F' and the function will return. The compiler sees this as:

```
if (*tel != 2) { 
  printf("Error\n");
}
*c = 'F';
return;
// The rest is ignored
```

You should explicitly use curly braces to mark if branches until you are quite comfortable with the definition of a statement in C++!